# YourMembership API - Session.Create = Unknown Error Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, api, response

I am attempting to create a call to YourMembership's API, specifically the Session.Create method.

```
function create_session(){
    var xml_create_session = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' +
    '<YourMembership>' +
    '<Version>' + ym_api_version + '</Version>' +
    '<ApiKey>' + ym_api_key + '</ApiKey>' +
    '<CallID>001</CallID>' +
    '<Call Method="Session.Create"></Call>' +
    '</YourMembership>';
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var session_id = xhttp.responseText.SessionID;
            authorize_token(session_id);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", api_url,true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(xml_create_session);  
}
```

When I submit this request to the API, I get the following response, which contains both the error sent by the API as well as the original request submitted to the API (note: I have redacted our API key, it was correct in the response):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<YourMembership_Response>
<ErrCode>999</ErrCode>
<ExtendedErrorInfo></ExtendedErrorInfo>
<ErrDesc>An unknown error has occured.</ErrDesc>
<XmlRequest>
<YourMembership>
<Version>2.02</Version>
<ApiKey>REDACTED</ApiKey>
<CallID>001</CallID>
<Call Method="Session.Create"></Call>
</YourMembership>
</XmlRequest>
</YourMembership_Response>
```

YourMembership states in their documentation that an API request must be submitted as an XML file via POST, and provide the following example for a call to Session.Create on their site (https://api.yourmembership.com/reference/2_02/Session_Create.htm):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<YourMembership>
    <Version>2.02</Version>
    <ApiKey>3D638C5F-CCE2-4638-A2C1-355FA7BBC917</ApiKey>
    <CallID>001</CallID>
    <Call Method="Session.Create"></Call>
</YourMembership>
```

It seems possible that this might be an issue specific to the platform, but it is also highly probable that there is something wrong with my JS or understanding of how to construct an XML file to send to the API, so any guidance is greatly appreciated! Thank so much!